# How to modify staticmethod decorator behavior?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, python-decorators

I was looking for a way how we can modify existing `staticmethod` decorator in python to add custom behavior. Say, calling another method in a class each time a static method is used.

I was stuck in a problem with MongoDB which required calling a method to manually set the Collection Name.

The following points give a description of the problem I'm stuck at:

1. I made a Database Class which acted as a wrapper for `pymongo`
2. I made 2 classes which used the **Database Class** I made for making transaction with `MongoDB`
3. Collection name's assigned to each class as a static variable
   *Example* :

   - User Class's collection name -> Users,
   - Quiz Class's collection name -> Quiz
4. Database Class (wrapper) maintained it's own `static variable` for *Collection* name, which was assigned by whichever class required to make transactions with the help of it.
5. The **PROBLEM**: Whenever I made a transaction for *Quiz* class first, it assigned Collection name to Database Class, but as soon as I made a transaction with *User* Class, *Quiz* Class's Collection name was used.
6. I made transactions using static methods in those Classes, The **SOLUTION** I thought of was modifying staticmethod in a way that it automatically reassigns the Collection name to the Database Class each time the static method is called.

Comment: Surely creating a new decorator would be better than changing the definition of `staticmethod`?

Comment: https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/

Comment: You could always create a decorator and decorate your inner func with `@staticmethod` but your linter wouldn't like you very much.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are trying to accomplish, and what you mean exactly by "modify existing staticmethod decorator". Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new decorator instead that calls `staticmethod`. I think this will work.

```
def customstatic(fun):
  def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
    def wrapper():
       return fun(*args, **kwargs)
    # do custom stuff here
    return staticmethod(wrapper)
  return decorator
```

Answer (score 0):

To add an alternative to @blueteeth 's answer.

This works but most linters will complain about it.

```
def custom_method(func):
    @staticmethod
    def static(*args, **kwargs):
        # do stuff
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return static
```